# Getting IDENTITY from dynamic INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In a stored procedure I am dynamically creating a query with a INSERT. This is done in order to force default values (like with @name if it is NULL).

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO table (username, password'
    + CASE @name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',name' END
    + ') VALUES (''root'',''gelehallon''' +
    + CASE @name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',''@name''' END
    + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

@id will be 0 no matter.
How can I retrieve the IDENTITY in a safe manner even if another thread is running the same stored procedure simultaneously?

Comment: Why are you dynamically creating a query in a stored procedure?

Comment: It is a way to force the default value on the fields that wasn't passed to the stored procedure. Let's say I might want @name, but if not passed, it should default to whatever is the default value for the table. Therefore I build it dynamically, removing @name if nothing was passed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO table (username, password) VALUES (@username,@pwd) 
    SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@username VARCHAR(50), @pwd VARCHAR(50), @id INTEGER OUTPUT', 
    'root', 'gelehallon', @id OUTPUT

-- @id now has SCOPE_IDENTITY() value in
```

Though a few points:
- assuming this is a simplified example as there doesn't seem to be a need to use dynamic SQL in this example
- assuming you're not going to store real passwords in plain text in the db!

Comment: *Laugh* No, it is a simplified example, and no, I am using salt and Sha1 for encryption. No worry. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: SHA1 is no longer seen as secure. SHA-2 is in SQL Server 2012 and above, or you can use something even more secure (eg bcrypt) with a some extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the OUTPUT clause with the INSERT statement. That will cause the dynamic statement, and, consequently, the system stored procedure used to invoke it, to return a rowset (one row in your case). You can grab at the chance and insert the rowset into a table variable, and then read the value.

Basically, it might look like this:

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO table (...) OUTPUT inserted.ID VALUES (...)';
DECLARE @ScopeIdentity (ID int);
INSERT INTO @ScopeIdentity
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @id = ID FROM @ScopeIdentity;
```